# How can I resolve Conda HTTP000error?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm currently having problems with Anaconda on a win10.

I've tried to update conda via the terminal and I get this error.

I've made a .condarc file, written http and https proxy in it, and 
set ssl_verify: False, but this error do not disappear.

What should I do?

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https//repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

The output from set CONDA command is shown below.

(env | grep CONDA can not used using win10 anaconda prompt)

```
(base) C:\Users\makoto.fujii>set CONDA
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\makoto.fujii\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\makoto.fujii\Anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\makoto.fujii\anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_SHLVL=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be an issue with a firewall, or a vpn.

To help troubleshoot, what is the output of this command?

```
conda config --show
```

One possible thing to try is to change the order of the channels in the .condarc file.

```
conda config --set client_ssl_cert None
conda config --set client_ssl_cert_key None
conda config --set  ssl_verify True
```

Update:

have you verified that you are not running a vpn or a firewall (the command below is for Windows Firewall)?

```
netsh interface show interface
netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state
```

also, can you ping the anaconda web-site?

```
ping anaconda.com
```

Comment: also, are you running "conda update [-n root] conda"? and if so, are you using a dos window or the anaconda window?

Comment: I'm running conda update conda using anaconda window.

Comment: I see a few differences in your configuration. 
Can you try to modify these 3 to match? 
You can set them back to the original values later. 


`client_ssl_cert: None`
`client_ssl_cert_key: None`
`ssl_verify: True`


command to change: 

`conda config --set client_ssl_cert None`
`conda config --set client_ssl_cert_key None`
`conda config --set  ssl_verify True`

Comment: I have executed these three commands, conda config --set client_ssl_cert None, 
 conda config --set client_ssl_cert_key None,  conda config --set  ssl_verify True.    But this error do not disappear. X)

Comment: what is the output from this command? 
`env | grep CONDA`

                 I can get the same error that you see, but only when i am using the DOS command prompt. When I use the conda window, I don't get this error. Wondering if you have multiple conda.exe files, and your command is pointing to the wrong one.

Comment: the output is  "env" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file X)

Comment: Ok. I have a few more things to check in the update section under my answer above (vpn, firewall and ping)

Comment: I have reinstalled windows10, then this error has disappeared.Something is wrong with my computer. Thank you for cooperation, Mr. Stierman.

Answer (score 0):

conda config --show output results